# Discord Bot CommandNotFound

Tags: python, discord, python-3.6, nextcord

```py
import nextcord
from nextcord import Interaction
from nextcord.ext import commands

# intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents= nextcord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Ready For Use!")


testingServerID = "server id"


@client.slash_command(name='hello', description="Replies with Hello", guild_ids=[testingServerID])
async def hello(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello There")


token = "my token token"
client.run(token)
'''
This is my first bot and I have asked people from discord but still no solution.
I have given it administrative prevailing, and every thing is needed from developers' side.
When I tried !hello and /hello, I get this error:
```

Bot is Ready For Use!
Ignoring exception in command None:
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found

Comment: You are getting that error because !hello does not exist.

Comment: @ConnerWolf08 yeah, but /hello exists, it didn't work either.
Is there anything to add such that the bot will work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create a text command called hello
you created a "SlashCommand"
The bot doesn't create a text command when you create a SlashCommand.
You either have to make a hybrid command (idk if it is avaliable in nextcord)

To create a hello command that works seprate from the Slash Command
You can try this:

```py
@client.command(name='hello', description="Replies with Hello")
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello There")
```